# documentLibrary not visible after creating site in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

I have a problem identifying the root folder **documentLibrary** after creating a new site.
I'm using a POST command to create a new site (to service/modules/create-site) and everything looks fine, the site is there. However, listing the folders show that there is no defaultLibrary. I need its ID in order to create new folders on the site visible on the web pages of Alfresco share.

My impression is that the **documentLibrary** is only created when you access for the first time the site on the web. Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: the correct name is documentLibrary

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The documentLibrary is created on the first access. You can use the siteService.getContainer method in the javascript services API. It will create the container if it does not exist: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_Services_API#Get_container_folder_for_component_id

I think the correct naming of the componentId is **documentLibrary**.

Comment: I'm not using JavaScript services. I guess I have to create the folder by hand

Comment: just call the HTTP service GET site/site_id/documentLibrary to create the doclib

Comment: Yup, the documentLibrary folder is created lazily when a user hits the page for the first time but as @alfrescian says you can fake this yourself with an extra GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by creating a folder for the template i use in Data Dictionary/Space Templates
Then the documentlibrary is created.